# Prevent caching of any data in my browser for mobile hybrid app.

Tags: caching, web-applications, browser-cache, hybrid-mobile-app

I host my app on the browser and I using a wrapper to load it on the mobile phone. I have huge problem with cashing data, anytime I make a change in the code, or different user log in I have to delete the app and install it again so I can see my changes. What should be done so I prevent caching .

I tried things that I read in this site about it but still I have the same issue.

I also save some data in the local storage browser